# How to select specific tagged part of a LaTeX document?

Tags: environments, compiling, tags

I am writing a wide set of exercises, that I tagged with different themes. A single exercise can of course be associated to different themes.

Is there a way to tag them (in a specific "exercise" environment for instance) so that I can compile only the list corresponding to a (unique, in my case) specific tag?

For instance, if I want to print out exercises on the theme of "normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$", I would like to compile my whole file with a single extra command/option so that it prints me exactly the exercises with the specific tag "normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$" (in practice, they will be numbers, if it can help).

I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: you  can obviously do something but it may require a change of your markup. As you have given no indication of the markup it is hard to help, but if you have something like `\begin{excercise}[tags=normed-vector-space,real]` then you can define `excercise` to loop through the tags and discard the environment if the required tags are not present

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the answer, I do not know how to do it. I haven't defined the environment yet and am starting to think about this project, so the environment can be designed to be suitable defined to make it easier if need be.

Comment: yes but given latex doesn't have anything called a tag (I don't think you mean `amsmath` command  `\tag`) or an `exercise`  it is hard to know what you have in mind unless you give some clues.  perhaps you just want to use `\newif\ifnormed` and surround things with `\ifnormed ...\fi` that will appear if `\normedtrue` and not appear if `\normedfalse`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking at something like \begin[111, 123, 245]{exercixe} for an exercise relevant for the themes 111, 123, 245. So they could be options, or extra list of arguments. And then I would like for instance to print out only exercises relevant for the theme 111.

Comment: Check the various packages for conditional compilation https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp and also the packages for exercises https://ctan.org/topic/exercise.